# Verify All Form Inputs Have Class

Tags: jquery, forms, class, input

I am trying to figure out how to check if all input elements in a particular form have a certain class, without checking each one individually if possible.

I know how to check if a single element has a class..

```
if( $('#element').hasClass('class') ){ Do This...}
```

I also know how to affect all inputs of a form with with a single line of JQuery.

```
$('#form > *').on('click', function(){ Do This...});
```

I just cant seem to blend the two...like...

```
if( $('#form > *').hasClass('class') ){ Do This...}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check if the count of inputs in form is equal to count of inputs in form with desired class:

```
var allHaveClass = $('#form input').length == $('#form input.yourclass').length;
```

Here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/2GnaW/

**Update**

An alternative approach: check if there's any input in form that does not have yourclass.

```
var allHaveClass = $('#form input:not(.yourclass)').length == 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
$("#form input").not('.theclass')
```

This would return any input elements that do not have that class.

An alternative method would be:

```
$("#form input:not(.theclass)")
```

The latter appears to have better performance.

Comment: This is definitely a good alternative to the other answers, thank you man!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be a simple `if` statement:

```
var form = $(formSelector);

if (form.find('input').length == form.find('input.className').length) {
    // all inputs have that class
}
```

Comment: It seems they were posted at pretty much the same time. And I'm glad to have green of some help.